# Thieves Guild quest "The Pursuit" incompletable: Karliah never shows up at the Ragged Flagon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim Special Edition*, I broke into Riftweald Manor earlier and stole Mercer's plans, before I did much with the Thieves Guild. Now when I try to start "The Pursuit" quest, which starts out with Karliah appearing at the Ragged Flagon, she doesn't appear. I've tried laying Mercer's plans back on the table, getting rid of them entirely, etc.

The Thieves Guild questline was the first thing I wanted to do with this character, but it's also the character that I wanted to complete everything with. This is the one questline that I cannot do. I really need a way to fix this. I am completely okay with using console commands.

I've tried using `resetinterior RiftenMercerFreyHouse` and `resetinterior 00037CC6`, both while in and outside of the house. Neither worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't find Karliah at the Ragged Flagon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41640/i-cant-find-karliah-at-the-ragged-flagon)

Comment: No. She does not appear at the ragged flagon, but "Pursuit" won't start. I've tried to teleport her there and she just leaves. I think I ended up following her to where she walks and I believe that it was somewhere near Dawnstar. She just stays there. 

I need Pursuit to start, and using "setstage TG07 0" does nothing. It should start the quest, but it doesn't.

Comment: This appears to be a very common bug. Unfortunately according to the Skyrim wiki's bug page on the quest, there is no known fix besides reloading an earlier save. However, there is a chance she is stuck at the Frozen Hearth. If you check the map, where is her pointer? If she is stuck try doing "setstage TG07 20" followed by "setstage TG07 30", then talk to Brynjolf and quest should continue as normal. It looks like you can also try re-taking the charcoal rubbing of the Falmer language to re-trigger "Hard Answers" to start.

Comment: She IS stuck at the frozen hearth. Using "sestage TG07 x" does nothing, as i noted above. The quest won't start. Talking to brynjolf does nothing. The best i can do is try to start TG09, but not TG08 or TG07. Neither will start through console commands

Comment: First of all, try the command 'setstage TG07 **10**', as the stage '0' does not exist (or is rarely used, at least). Furthermore, can you specify *in your question* how your situation differs from the duplicate I suggested? That those answers don't work for you doesn't rule your question out as a duplicate, and the main problem is still the same (Karliah does not appear in the Ragged Flagon, and The Pursuit won't start). If your situation is indeed crucially different, I will write an answer with more things you can try.

Answer (score 1):

> I broke into Riftweald Manor earlier and stole Mercer's plans, before I did much with the Thieves Guild.

If you don't have the [**Unofficial Skyrim Patch** (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266)) / [(PS4)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181) / [(Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804)  installed, you will encounter a bug with [The Pursuit](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Pursuit) quest if you steal Mercer's Plans before completing the [Hard Answers](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hard_Answers) quest (prerequisite quest to The Pursuit). The [UESP Wiki's The Pursuit - Bugs](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Pursuit#Bugs) article provides various solutions:

> - If you loot Mercer's Plans from Riftweald Manor prior to completing [Hard Answers](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hard_Answers) you will
>   be unable to progress through **The Pursuit** . Instead Karliah will
>   stand outside Snow Veil Sanctum and not move or speak with you.
>
>   - If you down her she will go to reenact the events at the end of [Speaking
>     with Silence](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speaking_With_Silence)
>     which will affect you as well if you are present. When you "awake"
>     again you will again be prompted to speak with Karliah but she will be
>     hostile. She will reset after a week and you can speak to her as if
>     you never completed Hard Answers. Returning Mercer's Plans to his home
>     prior to completing Hard Answers again will restore the quest chain.
>   - This issue has been addressed by version 1.0 of the [Unofficial Skyrim
>     Patch](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch);
>     The barrel people were using to gain early access to Mercer's House
>     has been moved away to avoid this very situation from happening.
>   - This bug happened because Mercer's Plans is in your inventory. Drop it
>     and enter console command `setstage tg07 10` will start the quest
>     normally.

There is also another similar bug where Karliah will not be at the Ragged Flagon during [The Pursuit](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Pursuit) quest. Also from the [UESP Wiki's The Pursuit - Bugs](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Pursuit#Bugs) article:

> - Karliah sometimes is stuck at [Winterhold Inn](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Frozen_Hearth) instead of
>   being in the [Ragged
>   Flagon](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Ragged_Flagon) at
>   beginning of the quest. This may happen if you leave the cellar before
>   Karliah does or complete other quests before continuing with this one.
>
>   - A possible solution is to go to the Flagon and move her via console commands: `prid 00058F1A` to select Karliah, followed by `moveto player` to move her to you. You may need to manually advance the quest
>     as well with `setstage tg07 20` .
>   - It is possible to re-enter the Dwemer Museum in Markarth. This will
>     reset the previous quest; run all the way back up and get the
>     translation off the stone in Calcelmo's tower again, and return to the
>     inn in Winterhold. The conversation with Karliah and Enthir should now
>     be reset. This time, when Karliah tells you to meet her at the Ragged
>     Flagon, wait until she leaves the cellar, and then wait there for a
>     day or so just to be sure. At this point the quest marker should
>     appear in Riften, indicating that Karliah is now where she should be.
>   - This bug may lead to conversation options allowing you to own more than one Nightingale Blade.